# How to link multiple javascript files where both files have an onload event?

Tags: javascript, html

I have two files file1 and file2 and am using window.onload in both files.
when am linking to these files in html

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="file1.js">
<script type="text/javascript" src="file2.js">
```

the second file is running (its onload event is triggered) while the first file is dead. what can I do to make both files run? Is there any other way than making a huge file (file1's content + file2's content)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM/EventTarget.addEventListener) :

```
window.addEventListener('load', function(){
```

Callbacks are all called, adding one doesn't remove the ones you added before.

If you want to be compatible with IE8, use a shim like this :

```
function addOnLoad(callback) {
    if (window.addEventListener) window.addEventListener('load', callback)
    else (window.attachEvent('onload', callback);
}

addOnLoad(function(){
```